# how to test two json file with pytest in python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, pytest

what would be the best way to test the case below with `pytest` with `python3`(3.6}+)?

```
json_data_one = {
   "id": 1,
   "status": True,
   "name": "Jhon"
}

json_data_two = {
   "id": 2,
   "status": False,
   "name": "Dave"
}
```

```
def foo(json_data_one, json_data_two):
    # not the best way to show this
    # but i want to loop through each json data then
    # show the result based on `status` is either `True` or `False`
    if json_data_one["status"] == True:
        return json_data_one
    elif json_data_two["status"] == False:
        return json_data_two

@pytest.mark.parametrize("status, name", [(True, "John"), (False, "dave")])
def test_foo(status, name):
    assert foo(status) == name
```

The above generate the error

```
status = True, name = 'John'

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("status, name", [(True, "John"), (False, "dave")])
    def test_foo(status, name):
>       assert foo(status) == name
E    TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'json_data_two'

test_start.py:46: TypeError
___________________________________________________________________________________________ test_foo[False-dave] ___________________________________________________________________________________________

status = False, name = 'dave'

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("status, name", [(True, "John"), (False, "dave")])
    def test_foo(status, name):
>       assert foo(status) == name
E    TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'json_data_two'

test_start.py:46: TypeError
========================================================================================= short test summary info ==========================================================================================
FAILED test_start.py::test_foo[True-John] - TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'json_data_two'
FAILED test_start.py::test_foo[False-dave] - TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'json_data_two'
```

I am a bit lost on how to implement it but what i want to accomplish is check each json data, then if `status == True` return `"name" == "John"` but if `status == False` return `"name" == "dave"`

I believe `parametrize` could be used but i am having a hard time figuring it out.

Thank you.

Comment: So what is the code you want to test?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen i have updated something above. and a bit of documentation to show what i am trying to achieve

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Yes, can you take a look above i have updated what i tried. This is my first time using parametrize if there is any mistake on the implementation could you please advise.

Comment: Yes, a simple mistake: instead of `"status", "name"` you need `"status, name"`, e.g. one string parameter only.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen that one string parameter only i have already tried it here is the error from the terminal `TypeError: test_foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'`

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I have updated the codes above to your suggestion and show the error from the terminal. any suggestion? Also the test is calling `foo`

Comment: Ah, I see now - you call the test function itself instead of the tested function! You need to call `foo` if you want to test it, but the `foo` code above doesn't make sense - what should it do?

Comment: @MrBeanBremenTrue, Thank you so much. I am looking forward to see your answer. I have updated the codes above now the error is `TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'json_data_two'`. Basically what i am trying to achieve is to loop through the two json data and check if `status == True` return all the data inside `json_data_one ` otherwise if `status == False` return all the data inside of `json_data_two`. I am trying to create a function and test with `pytest` that does that. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your actual function should probably look something like this:

```
def foo(json_data):
    if json_data["status"]:
        return json_data["name"]
    elif:
        return "Nope"
```

I don't know what you actually want to do, but the function as is does not make sense. You have to substitute your actual function, of course.

Then your test could look like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("data, result", [(json_data_one, "John"), 
                                          (json_data_two, "Nope")])
def test_foo(data, result):
    assert foo(data) == result
```

Again, your actual result is certainly something else, but I didn't understand what you are trying to do, so you have to adapt this.

Comment: I have updated the codes above now the error is `TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'json_data_two'`. Basically what i am trying to achieve is to loop through the two json data and check if `status == True` return all the data inside `json_data_one ` otherwise if `status == False` return all the data inside of `json_data_two`. I am trying to create a function and test with `pytest` that does that. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: updated...sorry about it the real codes dont have that typo

Comment: So, `json_data_one` and `json_data_two` are variables, and the values you assign to them are for the test only, right? Otherwise it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: That is correct. Only for the tests that I have created them.

Comment: So, if you write about looping over the data, you actually are passing an array? Or just 2 values?

Comment: First of all. Your codes suggested here work! Thank you. The only piece missing is to test with those two "cases" or "variables". An array can be used if you believe it is the right way to produce that outcome.